# applying the same operation to all tibbles within a list in R

Tags: r, list, lapply, tibble

I have created a list, elements of which of are (named) tibbles. I want to apply the same operation to all of the tibbles at once. I am sure this is easily achievable, but i couldn't find anything:

lets use the mtcars dat set. My list looks something like this, but much larger:

```
allData <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  group_map(~ head(.x, 2L))
```

Now, i want to calculate `ratio` which is hp/gear

in data.table i would just use:

```
dt[, ratio := hp/gear]
```

but i am not sure how apply the same operation to multiple tibbles organised in a list?

maybe it would be more efficient to convert them to some other format also?

i am planning to do more complicated operations with the tibbles, i am just trying to figure out how to do this on a simple example.

Comment: Depending on what you are doing, it might also be easier to stack each of the tibbles (`bind_rows()`), and then operate on them after a `group_by()` statement. It really depends on the complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it via `lapply` :

```
lapply(allData, function(x) transform(x, ratio = hp/gear))
#Or
lapply(allData, function(x) dplyr::mutate(x, ratio = hp/gear))
```

So if you some other complicated operations to do in each list you can extend the anonymous function.

```
lapply(allData, function(x) {
   x <- transform(x, ratio = hp/gear)
   #More things to do
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what `purrr` and the `map_*` family of functions is for. This is effectively the same thing as the `lapply()` solution, but you do not need to declare the anonymous function.

```r
library(purrr)

allData %>% 
  map( ~ mutate(.x, ratio = hp/gear))
```

You can make it more complex, including the familiar pipe.

```r
allData %>% 
  map( ~ .x %>% 
           mutate(ratio = hp/gear) %>%
           ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use

```
 lapply(allData, function(x) {x$ratio <- x$hp/x$gear; x})
```